# Perform Window Functions without OrderBy in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe where data is already in correct order.

Now i need to perform window functions like lead/lag on the dataframe ,but acc to Spark, orderBy is mandatory ,its not letting me like lead(col).over()

Is there any way to skip the orderBy ,because if i order by any col, the data order will be incorrect.

And the logic should work for large dataset too.

Comment: "I have a dataframe where data is already in correct order." This is true in `Pandas`.  Not true in distributed process like `PySpark`.

Answer (score 0):

No,in Spark, ordering the data is mandatory for window functions like `lead` and `lag`.
This is because window functions operate on a specific order of rows defined by the `ORDER BY` clause.
Without ordering the data, the window functions cannot determine which rows to include in the window frame.

I have tried the below approach:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, lead
schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("age", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True)
])
data = [("Rama", 25, "Female"), ("Jay", 30, "Male"), ("mahesh", 35, "Male")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
window = Window.orderBy("name")
df = df.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(window))
df = df.withColumn("next_name", lead("name", 1).over(window.orderBy("row_number")))
df.show()
```

```
+------+---+------+----------+---------+
|  name|age|gender|row_number|next_name|
+------+---+------+----------+---------+
|   Jay| 30|  Male|         1|     Rama|
|  Rama| 25|Female|         2|   mahesh|
|mahesh| 35|  Male|         3|     NULL|
+------+---+------+----------+---------+
```

Using the `row_number` window function will assign a unique sequential number to each row in the dataframe based on the order specified in the window specification,
Then you can perform the window function operations without actually ordering the dataframe.

This approach will work for large datasets too.